# How do I push image to appsrc and show it on d3d11videosink?

Tags: video-streaming, gstreamer, encode

I want to push a BGRA format image data to appsrc and show it in d3d11videosink.
Below is my pipeline command:

```
appsrc is-live=1 block=1 caps="video/x-raw,format="BGRA",width=2560,height=1440,framerate=30/1  name="appsrc" ! queue ! nvh264enc ! h264parse ! nvh264dec  ! d3d11videosink
```

When I run the app, it show the d3d11 render windows normaly and I can see the first frame of video, and then, the data flow is crash,   render windows stop in the first image, I can not see other image from appsrc. The render window still show there, it show debug message in terminal when I move mouse on it,but image will not flush.Below is debug message:

```
0:00:16.747392800 31728        301f770 DEBUG               GST_PADS gstpad.c:5954:gst_pad_send_event_unchecked:<appsrc:src> sent event, ret error
0:00:16.748135500 31728        301f770 LOG                 GST_PADS gstpad.c:5576:gst_pad_push_event_unchecked:<queue0:sink> sent event 00000000085fed50 (navigation) to peerpad <appsrc:src>, ret error
0:00:16.748593600 31728        301f770 DEBUG               GST_PADS gstpad.c:5954:gst_pad_send_event_unchecked:<queue0:src> sent event, ret error
0:00:16.749078700 31728        301f770 LOG                 GST_PADS gstpad.c:5576:gst_pad_push_event_unchecked:<nvh264enc0:sink> sent event 00000000085fed50 (navigation) to peerpad <queue0:src>, ret error
0:00:16.749734700 31728        301f770 DEBUG               GST_PADS gstpad.c:5954:gst_pad_send_event_unchecked:<nvh264enc0:src> sent event, ret error
0:00:16.750420200 31728        301f770 LOG                 GST_PADS gstpad.c:5576:gst_pad_push_event_unchecked:<h264parse0:sink> sent event 00000000085fed50 (navigation) to peerpad <nvh264enc0:src>, ret error
0:00:16.751051800 31728        301f770 DEBUG               GST_PADS gstpad.c:5954:gst_pad_send_event_unchecked:<h264parse0:src> sent event, ret error
0:00:16.751625100 31728        301f770 LOG                 GST_PADS gstpad.c:5576:gst_pad_push_event_unchecked:<nvh264dec0:sink> sent event 00000000085fed50 (navigation) to peerpad <h264parse0:src>, ret error
0:00:16.752132500 31728        301f770 DEBUG               GST_PADS gstpad.c:5954:gst_pad_send_event_unchecked:<nvh264dec0:src> sent event, ret error
0:00:16.752547700 31728        301f770 LOG                 GST_PADS gstpad.c:5576:gst_pad_push_event_unchecked:<autovideosink0:sink> sent event 00000000085fed50 (navigation) to peerpad <nvh264dec0:src>, ret error
0:00:16.752971900 31728        301f770 DEBUG               GST_PADS gstpad.c:5954:gst_pad_send_event_unchecked:<sink:proxypad0> sent event, ret error
0:00:16.753386000 31728        301f770 LOG                 GST_PADS gstpad.c:5576:gst_pad_push_event_unchecked:<autovideosink0-actual-sink-d3d11video:sink> sent event 00000000085fed50 (navigation) to peerpad <sink:proxypad0>, ret error
0:00:16.753822900 31728        301f770 LOG              GST_MESSAGE gstmessage.c:304:gst_message_new_custom: source autovideosink0-actual-sink-d3d11video: creating new message 00000000085c6c70 element
0:00:16.754258800 31728        301f770 WARN               structure gststructure.c:2093:priv_gst_structure_append_to_gstring: No value transform to serialize field 'event' of type 'GstEvent'
0:00:16.754760300 31728        301f770 DEBUG                GST_BUS gstbus.c:338:gst_bus_post:<bus0> [msg 00000000085c6c70] posting on bus element message: 00000000085c6c70, time 99:99:99.999999999, seq-num 112, element 'autovideosink0-actual-sink-d3d11video', GstNavigationMessage, type=(string)event, event=(GstEvent)NULL;
0:00:16.755206100 31728        301f770 DEBUG                    bin gstbin.c:3694:gst_bin_handle_message_func:<autovideosink0> [msg 00000000085c6c70] handling child autovideosink0-actual-sink-d3d11video message of type element
0:00:16.755655800 31728        301f770 DEBUG                    bin gstbin.c:4030:gst_bin_handle_message_func:<autovideosink0> posting message upward
0:00:16.756100600 31728        301f770 WARN               structure gststructure.c:2093:priv_gst_structure_append_to_gstring: No value transform to serialize field 'event' of type 'GstEvent'
0:00:16.756707100 31728        301f770 DEBUG                GST_BUS gstbus.c:338:gst_bus_post:<bus1> [msg 00000000085c6c70] posting on bus element message: 00000000085c6c70, time 99:99:99.999999999, seq-num 112, element 'autovideosink0-actual-sink-d3d11video', GstNavigationMessage, type=(string)event, event=(GstEvent)NULL;
0:00:16.757287700 31728        301f770 DEBUG                    bin gstbin.c:3694:gst_bin_handle_message_func:<pipeline0> [msg 00000000085c6c70] handling child autovideosink0-actual-sink-d3d11video message of type element
0:00:16.757866600 31728        301f770 DEBUG                    bin gstbin.c:4030:gst_bin_handle_message_func:<pipeline0> posting message upward
0:00:16.758386900 31728        301f770 WARN               structure gststructure.c:2093:priv_gst_structure_append_to_gstring: No value transform to serialize field 'event' of type 'GstEvent'
0:00:16.758964300 31728        301f770 DEBUG                GST_BUS gstbus.c:338:gst_bus_post:<bus2> [msg 00000000085c6c70] posting on bus element message: 00000000085c6c70, time 99:99:99.999999999, seq-num 112, element 'autovideosink0-actual-sink-d3d11video', GstNavigationMessage, type=(string)event, event=(GstEvent)NULL;
0:00:16.759514900 31728        301f770 DEBUG                GST_BUS gstbus.c:381:gst_bus_post:<bus2> [msg 00000000085c6c70] pushing on async queue
0:00:16.759972200 31728        301f770 DEBUG                GST_BUS gstbus.c:384:gst_bus_post:<bus2> [msg 00000000085c6c70] pushed on async queue
0:00:16.760435400 31728        301f770 DEBUG                GST_BUS gstbus.c:377:gst_bus_post:<bus1> [msg 00000000085c6c70] dropped
0:00:16.760917700 31728        301f770 DEBUG                GST_BUS gstbus.c:377:gst_bus_post:<bus0> [msg 00000000085c6c70] dropped
0:00:16.762531600 31728        301f770 LOG           d3d11videosink gstd3d11videosink.cpp:922:gst_d3d11_video_mouse_key_event:<autovideosink0-actual-sink-d3d11video> send mouse event mouse-move, button 0 (522.0, 56.0)
0:00:16.763236400 31728        301f770 DEBUG              GST_EVENT gstevent.c:337:gst_event_new_custom: creating new event 0000000008669650 navigation 53761
0:00:16.763868400 31728        301f770 LOG                 GST_PADS gstpad.c:5569:gst_pad_push_event_unchecked:<autovideosink0-actual-sink-d3d11video:sink> sending event 0000000008669650 (navigation) to peerpad <sink:proxypad0>
0:00:16.764577100 31728        301f770 DEBUG              GST_EVENT gstpad.c:5860:gst_pad_send_event_unchecked:<sink:proxypad0> have event type navigation event: 0000000008669650, time 99:99:99.999999999, seq-num 113, application/x-gst-navigation, event=(string)mouse-move, pointer_x=(double)522, pointer_y=(double)56, state=(GstNavigationModifierType)GST_NAVIGATION_MODIFIER_NONE;
0:00:16.765250900 31728        301f770 LOG                 GST_PADS gstpad.c:3162:gst_pad_event_default:<sink:proxypad0> default event handler for event navigation event: 0000000008669650, time 99:99:99.999999999, seq-num 113, application/x-gst-navigation, event=(string)mouse-move, pointer_x=(double)522, pointer_y=(double)56, state=(GstNavigationModifierType)GST_NAVIGATION_MODIFIER_NONE;
0:00:16.766058500 31728        301f770 LOG                 GST_PADS gstpad.c:3082:gst_pad_forward:<sink:proxypad0> calling forward function on pad autovideosink0:sink
0:00:16.766705400 31728        301f770 LOG                 GST_PADS gstpad.c:3127:event_forward_func:<autovideosink0:sink> Reffing and pushing event 0000000008669650 (navigation) to autovideosink0:sink
0:00:16.767289300 31728        301f770 LOG                 GST_PADS gstpad.c:5569:gst_pad_push_event_unchecked:<autovideosink0:sink> sending event 0000000008669650 (navigation) to peerpad <nvh264dec0:src>
0:00:16.767873200 31728        301f770 DEBUG              GST_EVENT gstpad.c:5860:gst_pad_send_event_unchecked:<nvh264dec0:src> have event type navigation event: 0000000008669650, time 99:99:99.999999999, seq-num 113, application/x-gst-navigation, event=(string)mouse-move, pointer_x=(double)522, pointer_y=(double)56, state=(GstNavigationModifierType)GST_NAVIGATION_MODIFIER_NONE;
0:00:16.768437800 31728        301f770 DEBUG           videodecoder gstvideodecoder.c:1881:gst_video_decoder_src_event:<nvh264dec0> received event 53761, navigation
0:00:16.768903600 31728        301f770 DEBUG           videodecoder gstvideodecoder.c:1781:gst_video_decoder_src_event_default:<nvh264dec0> received event 53761, navigation
0:00:16.769334300 31728        301f770 LOG                 GST_PADS gstpad.c:5569:gst_pad_push_event_unchecked:<nvh264dec0:sink> sending event 0000000008669650 (navigation) to peerpad <h264parse0:src>
0:00:16.769788100 31728        301f770 DEBUG              GST_EVENT gstpad.c:5860:gst_pad_send_event_unchecked:<h264parse0:src> have event type navigation event: 0000000008669650, time 99:99:99.999999999, seq-num 113, application/x-gst-navigation, event=(string)mouse-move, pointer_x=(double)522, pointer_y=(double)56, state=(GstNavigationModifierType)GST_NAVIGATION_MODIFIER_NONE;
0:00:16.770257200 31728        301f770 DEBUG              baseparse gstbaseparse.c:1705:gst_base_parse_src_event:<h264parse0> event 53761, navigation
0:00:16.770668000 31728        301f770 LOG                 GST_PADS gstpad.c:3162:gst_pad_event_default:<h264parse0:src> default event handler for event navigation event: 0000000008669650, time 99:99:99.999999999, seq-num 113, application/x-gst-navigation, event=(string)mouse-move, pointer_x=(double)522, pointer_y=(double)56, state=(GstNavigationModifierType)GST_NAVIGATION_MODIFIER_NONE;
0:00:16.771328700 31728        301f770 DEBUG               GST_PADS gstpad.c:2973:gst_pad_iterate_internal_links_default:<h264parse0:src> Making iterator
0:00:16.771753500 31728        301f770 LOG                 GST_PADS gstpad.c:3082:gst_pad_forward:<h264parse0:src> calling forward function on pad h264parse0:sink
0:00:16.772169000 31728        301f770 LOG                 GST_PADS gstpad.c:3127:event_forward_func:<h264parse0:sink> Reffing and pushing event 0000000008669650 (navigation) to h264parse0:sink
```

1.I try to change d3d11videosink to fakesink,the data flow is normaly.
2.I try the below pipeline,everything is ok
(1)Push image to appsrc and write the data to file with filesink:

```
appsrc is-live=1 block=1 caps="video/x-raw,format="BGRA",width=2560,height=1440,framerate=30/1 name="appsrc" ! queue ! videoconvert ! nvh264enc ! video/x-h264, stream-format=byte-stream ! h264parse ! nvh264dec ! queue ! videoconvert ! caps="video/x-raw,format="BGRA",width=2560,height=1440,framerate=30/1 ! filesink location="d:/output_video_bgra_raw.raw
```

(2)Read video stream from file and push it to appsrc, then show in d3d11videosink, everything is ok:

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location="d:/output_video_bgra_raw.raw" ! videoparse format=GST_VIDEO_FORMAT_BGRA width=2560 height=1440 framerate=30/1 ! queue ! nvh264enc ! h264parse ! nvh264dec ! videoconvert ! d3d11videosink
```